# How to implement forward progress bar

Tags: flutter, progress-bar

I am new to flutter and I wanted to implement countdown timer with multicolor custom linear progress bar. from left to right. i tried my best to implement this. but my progress Bar start from right to left and it ends before my countdown end. and i wants my progress bar start as my countdown start. but i am not understand how do i do that. so i give start button for this.how can i start my progress bar without start button and from left to right ?

here is my code

```
void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
 home: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
  actions: <Widget>[
     FlatButton(
        textColor: Colors.white, shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: 
Colors.transparent)),
         onPressed: () {},
         child: CountdownFormatted(
           duration: Duration(hours: 00, minutes: 2, seconds: 00),
           builder: (BuildContext ctx, String remaining) {
             return Text(
               remaining,
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
             ); // 01:00:00
           },
         )
     ),
  ],
  ),
  body: Center(
  child: ChangeNotifierProvider<TimeState>(
    create: (context) => TimeState(),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Consumer<TimeState>(
          builder: (context, timeState,_) => CustomProgressBar(
            width: 420,
            value: timeState.time,
            totalValue: 100,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Consumer<TimeState>(
          builder: (context, timeState, _) => RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Text("Start", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            onPressed: (){
              Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
                if(timeState.time == 0)
                  timer.cancel();
                else
                timeState.time -= 1;
              });
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
     ),
     ),
   )
  );
  } 
  }
  class CustomProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final int value;
  final int totalValue;

  CustomProgressBar({this.width, this.value, this.totalValue});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: implement build
  double ratio = value / totalValue;
  return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
   Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: width,
        height: 10,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[300]),
      ),
      Material(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        child: AnimatedContainer(
            height: 10,
            width: width * ratio,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: totalValue),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: (ratio < 0.3) ?
                Colors.red : (ratio < 0.6) ?
                Colors.orange : (ratio < 0.9) ?
                Colors.amber : Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
            )
        ),
      ),
    ],
    )
   ]
   );
   }
   }
  class TimeState with ChangeNotifier{
   int _time = 100;
   int get time => _time;
   set time(int newTime){
   _time = newTime;
    notifyListeners();
   }
   }
```

this code output looks something like this [image]

this progress Bar start from backward and I want it from forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your source code. The problem is in width that you have specified. You are using timer and based on you are specifing your width. You are starting timer from maximum value which is your full width. That's why it is starting from full width and keep reducing as your timer is reducing from maximum time.

Change width of `AnimatedContainer` to `width: width - (width * ratio),`

Comment: Thank You. can you please help me out how i start my progress bar with countdown instead of start button